# What is a principal extension?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

I am attempting the following problem from Stevenhagen's book on Algebraic Number Theory.

> Show that the maximal order in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{-31})$ has class number 3. Show that a rational prime $p$ has a principal extension of norm $p$ in this order if and only if $p$ is of the form $p = x^2 + 31y^2$.

I am struggling to figure out what he means by "principal extensions of norm $p$". It isn't discussed in the text. I can't even find anything online. Can anyone familiar what this content provide any insight?

Comment: they mean a principal ideal containing $p$, of norm $p$